# Not selector for prevent triggering parent event

Tags: jquery, html

I have following html code

```
<div class="overlay" data-url="http://www.example1.org">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit

   <a class="link1 clickThis" href="http://www.example2.org">
     first link
  </a>
  <a class="link2 clickThis" href="http://www.example3.org">
     Second link
  </a>`
</div>
```

I can not directly make link to overlay div, I want to redirect to respected url after clicking div and links, when user click on link then it should be redirect on particular url.
But if user click at out side of a then it should redirect to url that set to data-url attribute.

So that I had written this JQuery code

```
$('.overlay').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-url');
    }).children('a').click(function(event) {
         return false;  
    });

// methods call on link click
$(document).on('click', '.clickThis', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            param1: 'value1'
        },
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
});
```

but this is not working after clicking on links

also tried this

```
$('.overlay:not(.link1,.link2)').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-url');
    });
```

please specify the correct answer. 
thanks.

Comment: can you fiddle the problem ?

Comment: yes, please check this   http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/40kxxc7m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot Stop Propagation on "a" or they will stop working..
try:

```
$('.overlay').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if(event.target.localName != 'a'){
       window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-url');
   }
});
```

Comment: You stop propagation on `a` to stop the event from bubbling up.  It's not true that stopping propagation on an anchor will prevent it from working

Answer (score 2):

You need to [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) on the anchor.  You are currently using *`return false`* which prevents the default behavior of the anchor from happening.  By stopping propagation on the anchor it prevents the event from bubbling up to the ancestor elements.

> event.stopPropagation()
>
> > Returns: Description: Prevents the event from
> >     bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being
> >     notified of the event.

```
$('.overlay').click(function(event) {
      window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-url');
 }).children('a').click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Since you are using ajax for the anchor you can use `return false` or `stopPropagation() + preventDefault()`

```
$('.overlay').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-url');
}).children('a').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            param1: 'value1'
        },
    }).done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    return false;  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, not working, actually the links are some click methods, I am getting the data by ajax after clicking on link, please check the the question now. Thanks.

Comment: no, not getting any error on console, you can check this http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/40kxxc7m

Comment: @Devidas - You need to add jQuery in the drop down on the left for your fiddle.  Also if you just use the code I added after the initial answer it should fix your issue

Comment: added jQuery as external resource, problem is solved by accepted answer. thank you.